# How can you wipe and reinstall OSX on a Mac Mini (which has no optical drive)?

Tags: macos, mac-mini, install

If you are a new disk and wiping them to setup a DIY Fusion disk, how does the Mini carry on working afterwards... haven't you just wiped the OS? Without an optical drive, how can you clean the disks and still be able to reinstall an OS?

Comment: I found this, might help - https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5815647 Note, on a barebones machine, the OS will be downloaded by Recovery if there's no existing partition. It will download the OS the machine was first sold with.

Comment: Can you go into more detail on "Recovery" - does it 'magically' get an OS from the web or is there a secret recovery partition?

Comment: On a fully installed system, there's a hidden partition, on a new drive it will use the magic of the interwebz to fetch the OS. See http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4718

Answer (score 2):

> Without an optical drive, how can you clean the disks and still be
>   able to reinstall an OS?

Simplest and cheapest way: `create a bootable volume from the OS X Installer on a USB Stick.`

2 days ago I used the (free) [DiskMakerX](http://diskmakerx.com) to clone the `10.10.3 OS X Installer` (it works also with older OS X versions) from `AppStore` to a `USB Stick` and used that *bootable clone* to start from it and install `OS X` on another volume. Everything worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

You could also try `Internet recovery`

To do this boot your Mac while holding <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> Then when it loads (takes about 5 mins) go to `disk utility` and format your drive. After you have done that go back and select the option `Reinstall OS X`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This [guide](http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/os-x-yosemite-usb-installer-public-beta/) explains how to create a bootable USB installer, from the installer you'll be able to wipe the internal disk through disk utility before installation

Answer (score -1):

I have been able to use OS X purchases from my App Store and use for clean install. Assuming you have gotten updates since lion was released? Go to your purchases and option + click the OS you want installed. The limit is naturally set so you cannot load an OS older then your machine.